# Range and nullspace of this $4 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a linear map from $\Bbb R ^2 \to \Bbb R ^4$ be given by $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 && 1 \\ 2 && 2 \\ 3 && 3 \\ 4 && 4 \end{matrix} \right)$.

Now I know the null-space is everything in the form $(x,-x)$, so it is $1$-dimensional.

Apparently the range is also $1$-dimensional; however, if I apply my matrix to $\left( \begin {matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right)$, I get $\left( \begin{matrix} x+y \\ 2(x+y) \\ 3(x+y) \\ 4(x+y) \end{matrix} \right)$.

Furthermore, shouldn't $\dim null + \dim range = \dim whole \, space$? However, according to the solution of the problem, this would be $1+1 = 2$, but since we are in $\Bbb R ^4$ shouldn't the dimension of the range be $3$, which is not what the solution says, anyway?

Comment: The dimensions should sum to 2, which is the dimension of the *domain*. This is because the domain, modded out by the kernel, is isomorphic to the image (range).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake comes from the fact that you think of the dimension of the codomain, instead of the dimension of the domain. $1 + 1 = 2$ which is the dimension of the domain, not the codomain!

Answer (score 0):

Your rank is $1$ and nullity is $1$.

Rank+nullity= dim $(\mathbb{R^2})$

Comment: The official  answers  say that both that the dimension of the range and nullspace are both 1.

Comment: official means? Is it from some book?

Comment: The rank and nullity are both 1 and sum to 2 which is the dimension of the domain, which is correct.

Comment: The nullity cannot have dimension $3$, given that the domain of definition has dimension $2$, come on!!